# Xcode - Entering tags into a textview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have been struggling for quite some time to solve this problem since I haven't found any useful answers here or elsewhere.

My Question:
I have an application where the user should be able to enter tags into a UITextView and every time he presses return the tag will be surrounded by an outline. This pretty much the exact same thing as with the tags on this site. I have been experimenting with different styling options of the textView and looking for solutions in the UITextViewDelegate but couldn't find anything so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try this https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Comment: I would suggest to find a third-party library to do this for you, it should save time and effort...